# Outputting and Compressing CSS files with PHP

Tags: php, css, caching, compression, obfuscation

I'm generating CSS from files everytime when user enters to the page like this:

```
<?php

header("Content-type: text/css");
$styles = array(
    'default',
    'reset',
    'notifybar',
    'jqui'
);
if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
    if (file_exists('styles/' . trim($_GET['page']) . '.css'))
        $styles [] = $_GET['page'];
    switch ($_GET['page']) {
        case "main":
            $styles [] = "treeview";
            $styles [] = "buttons";
            $styles [] = "wmd";
            $styles [] = "qa";
            $styles [] = "pretify";
            $styles [] = "code";
            $styles [] = "msgBoxes";
            break;
        case "payments":
            $styles [] = "tables";
            break;
    }
}

foreach ($styles as $style) {
    include 'styles/' . $style . '.css';
}
?>
```

And HTML gets CSS like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="design/css.php?page=<?= $pgdata['token'] ?>" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

I got 2 questions:

1. Can I cache css files for better performance? If yes, then how?
2. How can I compress the css files during output? I mean something like obfuscation: removing empty line breaks, spaces.. in other words creating production version of css. If possible, help me to do it with caching. Thx in advance

Comment: Caching on the client or server?  (You can do both - of course).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the PHP5 library [minify](https://github.com/mrclay/minify).

It does minify, cache and concatenate JS and CSS files, so it could be solution.
Here's a walkthrough on how to implement it: http://www.mrclay.org/2008/09/19/minify-21-on-mrclayorg/

Comment: How can I use it, inside my PHP file?

Comment: Instead of using it in your PHP file, you can minify all your CSS files in place, creating styles/$style.min.css files. Then have your PHP file access these in the include statements.